# Unlock a record which is locked by approval process

Tags: apex, approval-process

I don't see a way to unlock a record that is locked by approval process.IsLocked flag is not accessible through api.Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of Winter '16, this is now possible through APEX. ([Release Notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks.htm#rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks))

It can be enabled by going to *Setup* > *Create* > *Workflow & Approvals* > *Process Automation Settings* :

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### EDITOR NOTE

As mentioned in other answers, this feature is now possible out of the box as of Winter '16.

### Original Answer

not out of the box.

What we did in a client project was:

1. Create RecordLockStatus__c picklist field with valuess [UNLOCKED, IN_APPROVAL, LOCKED]
2. Create UnlockToken__c text field
3. Create an approval process with entry criteria
   RecordLockStatus__c='LOCKED' and UnlockToken__c = ?SEMI_SECRET_TOKEN? to prevent accidental unlock and sets RecordLockStatus__c='UNLOCKED' and UnlockToken__c=NULL. **Make sure to set the approval's order to 1**.
4. For all your other approvals make sure that you set RecordLockStatus__c= 'IN_APPROVAL' when entering the approval and RecordLockStatus__c='LOCKED' when locking the record on finish
5. To unlock your record query it (make sure
   RecordLockStatus__c='LOCKED') and submit for approval using Apex
   http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_process.htm

hope that helps

Comment: Will the record gets unlock without taking ownership of record after following your above steps?

Comment: that depends on how you setup the approval. following the steps above it wont, but of course you and re-assign the record in the unlock workflow if needed

Comment: I know this is kindof an old bump but SF has an example of approving/rejecting a record in Apex. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_process_example.htm

Comment: sf.dev, did this work for you?

Comment: You can now: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks.htm

Answer (score 1):

Apex doesn't expose any class/method to unlock a record. There are only two ways a record can be unlocked that is locked by the approval process.

- The 'Final Approval Action' of the process does have the feature to unlock a record.
- A button labelled 'Unlock record' will be visible (only)to system administrators and only they can unlock a record locked by an approval process.