# Unlock a record when submitting for approval

Tags: approval-process

Is it possible NOT to lock a record when submitting it for approval?
I cannot find any setting where I might be able to change this. Any idea?
Tia, Lily.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow the user to recall the submitted record and then the user can do the editing and then user can resend the record for approval.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16373/unlock-a-record-which-is-locked-by-approval-process)'s first and second answer.

There's no easy way to do it, you'd have to use Apex.